# macOS app icon stuck on my screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, icon, launchpad

I just tried to open Spotify's Mac app through the OS X LaunchPad, and when I clicked on the icon, the Mac app icon remains stuck on my screen.

I've attached some screenshots to show you. I don't know how to get it down. No matter what I do to the screen, the icon is always stuck "on top" of it.

How do I make this go away? If you're curious, Spotify opened on the second attempt. The first attempt it just got stuck.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: I have a ton of things open for work, I was hoping to avoid that...

Comment: I think ending your session (log out) or restarting the computer as suggested, may actually be the solution here. If you have a myriad of items open for work as you say, what makes it so difficult to just save the work, close the applications and then move on? No offense, but this sounds trivial to me.

Comment: As AntonTheGreat mentions in a reply on this page, if it's a launchpad icon, open launchpad and click and hold an icon as if you are going to move it. That fixes the issue.

Comment: Holding an icon as if I'm going to move it does not (no longer?) work as of at least 10.15.7.

Comment: 6 years later...  Latest mac and everything. The bug is still here :)

Comment: Really funny and painful to see the struggle. I faced the same. :D

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Turns out, I just had to reset the 'dock' process. I opened Terminal and typed

```
killall Dock
```

and pressed enter. The screen flashed for a second, and everything came back with my stuck icon gone.

If that fails, the issue may be with Finder (this is the case with the similar issue of [Stacks](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209101) categories "burned in" to your desktop background). Running

```
killall Finder
```

will address that.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Much better than having to reboot!

Comment: In case anyone misses answer further down: `killall Finder` works if this one doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've had so much downtime from this happening over and over.

Comment: Super helpful, this happens to me frequently,

Comment: this helps, as I see the Dock restarted by itself

Comment: I prefer the answers that do not involve killing processes.  For example, I just opened the launchpad, found the original location of the icon that was stuck, moved it, and it went away.  I bet the moving any icon answer from AntonTheGreat works too.

Comment: Works. Make sure you use Dock and not dock.

Answer (score 31):

The easiest fix is to just open the app drawer, holding any icon until the move motion occurs, then move any application; it seems to fix it everytime it happens for me.

Comment: or launchpad in this case!  i bet it'll fix the issue anytime it happens!

Comment: I wish you posted this a few hours sooner! I figured it out this morning and am going to write up the answer that I used now

Comment: Yes, this approach was easy!  I simply did this: 1) Open LaunchPad, 2) Click and hold on any icon, to get them to wiggle (like on an iPhone).

Comment: Always works. It worked on Catalina and continues to work on Big Sur

Comment: I come here to say thank you, 7 years later the bug still exists in macOS 14.1.1 Sonoma, and the fix still works!

Answer (score 11):

What I do is pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> then relaunch Finder app.
[image: Force Quit or Relaunch Finder.app]
Works for me.

Comment: `killall Finder` worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me on High Sierra.

Answer (score 5):

Same thing!!

Very simple solution: Just search look for the original icon in the launch pad and drag it!

Apparently this is a drag action that never completed.

Answer (score 1):

I found an amazing solution for this and i am so happy because i suffer from this problem for few years now !!!!
the trick is like this: press F4 to show all apps, and drag one of the apps icon over the logo that is stuck on your screen, and voila ! it makes it gone ! hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me with Firefox recently. The way I got the icon to go away was to delete all desktop spaces except one. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Interesting. I already have only 1 space. But, making a new one makes it disappear, then moving back to the original and it's still there.

Comment: Strange. I think I added and removed spaces a few times and then it suddenly went away for good.

Comment: I tried that. Thanks for the suggestion, but I couldn't get it to go away. :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an app that won't to go away and was in the top of every window.

I installed htop (`brew install htop`) and searched for a part of the app name (`F3`), which brings me another app inside the app's folder.

Just pressed `F9` and killed it. (Press `q` to quit htop)

The executable was not listed on Activity monitor, so htop helped me to find and kill it.

Answer (score -2):

Working solution for me:

start the application that stuck to screen in launchscreen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -

Comment: This doesn't help. Also, the question by OP confirms this as well.

Comment: That doesn't work. Most importantly because the app is already running.